# Multiple Rasters into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster

This may have been asked before, but
A) what software/libraries etc do I need to
B) load multiple rasters into PostGIS?

I have Python 2.7.5, QGIS 1.9 (latest Weekly Build), PostGIS (whatever the latest version is) and I've downloaded the latest batch of GDAL codecs)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Steve

Comment: equally I keep seeing lots of pages saying to use raster2pgsql - but do I run this Command Prompt, in Python, in QGIS? (I've tried all three so far with no success!)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65848/loading-raster-data-to-postgis/66135#66135 you run the command in postgres pgadminIII or for windows the command prompt logged into postgres

Comment: Is that in the PSQL Console in pgAdminIII?

Comment: yes the PSQL Console in pgAdminIII under Plugins

Comment: The thing is nothing happens - I try the following: raster2pgsql -s <srid> -t 50x50 -f -I -Y c:/Temp/*.tif MyRaster2 > C:/Temp/raster.sql
psql -h localhost -U Postgres -d home -f C:/Temp/raster.sql       as per the other page and I get nothing happening, no .sql script is created (or if it is I don't know where on my PC it is creating it!)

Comment: whoops, noticed that I didn't write in the SRID, but even still using 27700 in place of <SRID> brings me no joy!

Comment: You use the `-f` option, which specifies the name of the destination raster column, but you don't specify a name. Like this, raster2pgsql will set "-I" as column name instead of interpreting -I as an option. See http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_raster.xml.html for more info. I assume that you separated the two commands (raster2pgsql, psql) by a semicolon. Consider piping them (using the | character) instead of saving the commands to a .sql each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work - I needed to add the folder where the raster2pgsql is located into the environmental variables - Path  on the computer. This enabled me to run the application in cmd, although not within pgAdminIII for some reason...

Comment: Could you mark this as the answer, so it gets "closed off". Thanks