# Upload TIFF files to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql

New to the GIS, I want to upload these file formats to PostgreSQL server

```
.tfw
.tif
.tif.aux.xml
tif.vat.cpg
tif.vat.dbf
tif.xml
tif.ovr
```

I used the standard `org2ogr` way to upload files but it wouldn’t recognise any these formats, as none of the drivers listed in the error message support these file formats.
I’ve also noticed I don’t have `raster2pgsql.exe` in my `Postgresql/13/bin/` directory. What might be the solutions?

(Edited to include `gdalinfo` as requested)

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\filepath\filename.tif
       C:\filepath\filename.tif.ovr
Size is 43201, 15779
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,72.000059984999993)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333332238,-0.008333333332214)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  72.0000600) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 72d 0' 0.22"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -59.4916067) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 59d29'29.78"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0083333,  72.0000600) (180d 0'30.00"E, 72d 0' 0.22"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0083333, -59.4916067) (180d 0'30.00"E, 59d29'29.78"S)
Center      (   0.0041666,   6.2542267) (  0d 0'15.00"E,  6d15'15.22"N)
Band 1 Block=43201x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=4.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=4.000, Mean=nan, StdDev=nan
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 21601x7890, 10801x3945, 5401x1973, 2701x987, 1351x494, 676x247, 338x124
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=4
    STATISTICS_MEAN=nan
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=nan
```

Comment: Did you install PostGIS? If not, you will have to as you will not find `raster2pgsql.exe` as it's related to PostGIS, the PostgreSQL spatial extension not PostgreSQL itself

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65848/loading-raster-data-to-postgis

Comment: ahh yes! I've got PostGIS extension installed now @ThomasG77. `ogr2ogr` still wouldn't work with the extension so I went for `raster2pgsql`. I have been running this overnight in Powershell and still not completed `.\raster2pgsql -s 4326 -F -I "C:\users\download\file.tif" | .\psql -h xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U myaccount -d dbname`. It's only a 25mb file, is that normal? what causes it to be stuck at `processing 1/1` for so long and that I also need to upload its attribute files `.tif.ovr` etc....separately.

Comment: Ogr2ogr converts data between vector formats https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html. Gdal_translate takes care of the rasters. Unfortunately the PostGIS raster driver in GDAL is read-only. So raster2pgsql is the tool to use. Your experience of speed is certainly not normal. Please add gdalinfo about your source data if it happens to reveal something.

Comment: @user30184 I've upadated my post with `gdalinfo`, please take a look! it is a global file so I wonder if the indexing `-I` had slowed down the speed. The indexing is 'nice to have', and if this is the reason causing speed issue I'd rather removed it.

Comment: The image at full resolution is organized into rows `Block=43201x1`. I do not know what is the default tilesize that raster2pgsql is using, but if it was128x128 it means that (128 rows) x (43201 pixels per row) must be read before the first tile can be written. Pre-processing the original into tiled image would probably help `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw input.tif output.tif`. Another option could be to give more memory for GDAL that raster2pgsql is maybe using on the background with https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_CACHEMAX.

Comment: @user30184 will using a more powerful laptop help? Thanks for the tips, `gdal_translate` tiled my file within seconds but after 30hours the tiled file is still uploading… I’m using a i7 CPU and 16GB RAM laptop.  From [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781784391645/1/ch01lvl1sec7/loading-rasters-using-raster2pgsql) `raster2pgsql` automatically works out a default range of 32-100.

Comment: 30 hours for processing such a smallish image means that something is badly wrong. Acquiring more raw power is not the right thing to do. Have you tried to run raster2pgsql with explicit tile size like `-t 128x128`?

Comment: Yep I ran it at `-t 128x128` after reading your comment @user30184. It had taken the entire day again so I ended up cancelling the upload. I start to think if it has anything to do with the file or the server itself. I thought about stripping off colour bands that I don’t need but obviously there’s only one colour band here. The file is coming from the global landslide susceptibility map hyperlink [here](https://gpm.nasa.gov/applications/landslides#modelingandreportinglandslides)